# How to have a follow/unfollow button on a user's post

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-views

I have been trying make users follow other users from thier posts like in instagrams explore page. Currently a user can just follow and unfollow other users from their profile but I will like to have that follow/unfollow on their posts too. I tried to make this happen but in the process I got a NameError `name 'username' is not defined`, How can I fix this error in order to make this work?

models.py (mates model is where the follow/unfollow should go)

```
class Mates(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='usermates', unique=True)
    req_bio = models.CharField(max_length=400)

class Following(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    followed = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="followed")
    follower = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="follower")

    @classmethod
    def follow(cls, user, another_account):
        obj, create = cls.objects.get_or_create(user = user)
        obj.followed.add(another_account)
        print("followed")

    @classmethod
    def unfollow(cls, user, another_account):
        obj, create = cls.objects.get_or_create(user = user)
        obj.followed.remove(another_account)
        print("unfollowed")

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics', null=True, blank=True, default='default.png')
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=400, default=1, null=True)
    connection = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank=True)
    follower = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    following = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        img  = Image.open(self.profile_pic.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300,300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.profile_pic.path)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

views.py

```
def matesmain(request):
    if request.user.has_posts():
        contents = Mates.objects.filter(
            categories__in=['action', 'sports', 'shooter', 'battle_royale', 'adventure', 'racing']
        )
        mates_owner = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
        
        context = {
            'contents': contents,
            'mates_owner': mates_owner,

        }
        print("nice3")
        return render(request, 'mates.html', context)
    else: 
        return render(request, 'mates-error.html')

def follow(request, username):
    main_user = request.user
    to_follow = User.objects.get(username=username)
    following = Following.objects.filter(user = main_user, followed = to_follow)
    is_following = True if following else False 

    if is_following:
        Following.unfollow(main_user, to_follow)
        is_following = False
    else:
        Following.follow(main_user, to_follow)
        is_following = True
    resp = {
        'following': is_following,
    }

    response = json.dumps(resp)
    return HttpResponse(response, content_type="application/json")
```

html

```
{% if connection and not request.user == mates_owner %}
    <a type="button" class="button-caballo" id="follow" role="button" href="{% url 'follow' mates_owner.username %}">Unfollow</a>
{% elif not connection and not request.user == mates_owner %}
    <a type="button" class="button-caballo" id="follow" role="button" href="{% url 'follow' mates_owner.username %}">Follow</a>
{% endif %}
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('follow/<str:username>', views.follow, name='follow')
    path('mates-main', views.matesmain, name='mates-main'),
]
```

traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\startup\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\startup\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\startup\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\startup\gstartup\startup_home\views.py", line 126, in matesmain
    mates_owner = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
NameError: name 'username' is not defined
[16/Jul/2020 08:53:25] "GET /mates-main HTTP/1.1" 500 70246
```

Comment: please post the full traceback.

Comment: You didn't define username in matesmain view

Comment: @riNg Hey, would it work if I use `userame = User.objects.all()`? if not how would I define it?

Comment: @ewong I just posted full traceback can you check it please?

Comment: @JuanMartinZabala you can try ``username = request.user.username``. Make sure that user has authenticated

Comment: Hey! @riNg your code seems to be on the right way, except the buttons(links) doesnt display on the page because I think there is no connection filed on mates model, can you confirm that?